# llenar dropdownlist en gridview y el maximo valor debe ser el valor que tiene una de las celdas

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, aplicación-web

tengo un gridview con productos de una tienda listando algunas caracteristicas, entre ellas la cantidad de productos en stock entonces el usuario no deberia poder seleccionar un valor mayor al numero en stock(existencias)

tengo este gridview y necesito agregar una columna con un DropDownlist y este DropDownList debe tener valores desde el cero y el maximo valor debe ser el valor que esta en la columna de Existencias.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Existencias")) > 0 %>' runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo" DataField="IdProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Marca" DataField="NomMarca"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ciudad" DataField="NomCiudad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tamaño" DataField="Tamano"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fragilidad" DataField="NomFragilidad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ubicacion" DataField="NomUbicacion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Proveedor" DataField="NomProveedor"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Producto" DataField="NomProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion" DataField="Descripcion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Existencias" DataField="Existencias"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Venta" DataField="PrecioVenta"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Compra" DataField="PrecioCompra"/>

    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: No sé como estas cargando el grid con la información, pero podrías hacer antes de asignar la data al grid un método que agregue un item con contador hasta Existencia y le asignas el resultado a un dropdown que pongas en el grid, por cada registro del grid

Comment: Pensaba que podria desarrollar la logica en asp markup en lugar de hacerlo en el code behind

Answer (score 1):

muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

ya lo solucione de la siguiente manera

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="Termino no encontrado" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Seleccionar">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Existencias")) > 0 %>' ID="chk" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chk_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cantidad">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCantidad1" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Existencias")) > 0 %>' runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Codigo" DataField="IdProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Marca" DataField="NomMarca"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ciudad" DataField="NomCiudad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tamaño" DataField="Tamano"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Fragilidad" DataField="NomFragilidad"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ubicacion" DataField="NomUbicacion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Proveedor" DataField="NomProveedor"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Producto" DataField="NomProducto"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Descripcion" DataField="Descripcion"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Existencias" DataField="Existencias"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Venta" DataField="PrecioVenta"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Precio de Compra" DataField="PrecioCompra"/>
    </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
    </asp:GridView>


foreach (GridViewRow gv1row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            int existenciasValue = int.Parse(gv1row.Cells[11].Text);
            for (int i = 0; i <= existenciasValue; i++)
            {
                int ix = gv1row.RowIndex;
                DropDownList DdlCantidad = GridView1.Rows[ix].FindControl("DdlCantidad1") as DropDownList;
                //llenar dropdownlist aqui
                DdlCantidad.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero encontré tu pregunta y me puse a solucionarla y aquí esta:

Antes de proceder:

- El DropDownList se debe cargar mediante una función que retorne los valores y que recibe un parámetro (que es el máximo de elementos que tendrá).
- Yo en mi ejemplo cargo el GridView y el DropDownList mediante controles ObjectDataSource.

### Este es el control GridView del lado de cliente:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPrueba" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="ODS_gvPrueba" OnRowDataBound="gvPrueba_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="id_existencias"/>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Existencias">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtExistencias" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("existencias") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Combo existencias">
            <ItemTemplate>
                //<%-- DropDownList que es cargado a través de un control ObjectDataSource --%>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExistencias" runat="server"     
                    DataTextField="existencias_dll" 
                    DataValueField="id_existencias_dll" DataSourceID="ODS_ddlExistencias">
                </asp:DropDownList>

                //<%-- Á través de un control HiddenField se pasará el valor de existencias a la función que carga nuestro DDL --%>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfExistencias" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("existencias") %>'/>

                //<%-- Control ObjectDataSource que carga el control DropDownList "ddlExistencias" dentro del GridView --%>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS_ddlExistencias" runat="server" SelectMethod="cargar_dllExistencias" TypeName="Solución___GridView_DDL.Existencias" OnSelecting="ODS_ddlExistencias_Selecting">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfExistencias" Name="existencias" Type="String" PropertyName="Value"/>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### En la parte del código del lado de servidor:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //Variable que será accesible por los métodos; 
    //De esta forma podremos pasar un valor de un método a otro.
    private String _numero;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Método OnRowDataBound del control GridView
    protected void gvPrueba_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlExistencias");
            String valor_hf = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfExistencias")).Value;

            _numero = valor_hf;
            ddl.DataBind();
        }
    }

    //Método OnSelecting del control ObjectDataSource que es el que carga los datos del DropDownList dentro del GridView
    protected void ODS_ddlExistencias_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.InputParameters["existencias"] = _numero;
    }
}
```

En mi ejemplo, uso estas funciones que cargan los controles GridView y DropDownList respectivamente.

### GridView

```
public DataTable cargar_gvPrueba() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id_existencias");
    dt.Columns.Add("existencias");

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        var dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["id_existencias"] = i;
        dr["existencias"] = i * 5;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

### DropDownList

```
public DataTable cargar_dllExistencias(String existencias) {
    if (existencias == "") { existencias = "0"; }

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("id_existencias_dll");
    dt.Columns.Add("existencias_dll");

    int exist = Convert.ToInt32(existencias);
    for (int i = 0; i <= exist; i++) {
        var dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr["id_existencias_dll"] = i;
        dr["existencias_dll"] = i;

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Te pegué puro código, lo sé, pero también me tomé la libertad de hacer un video explicando todo esto, el cuál puedes ver en el siguiente [enlace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ybs7sCdOI2o).